AWS Gunicorn configuration Amazon Linux Work not properly
enter image description here
This image is show problem.
When i run gunicorn service with this configuration.
  GNU nano 5.8                                                                      pair.service                                                                                 
[Unit]
Description=Gunicorn instance to serve Pair
After=network.target

[Service]
PermissionsStartOnly=true
User=ec2-user
Group=ec2-user
WorkingDirectory=/usr/share/nginx/html/pair
Environment="PATH=/usr/share/nginx/html/pair/venv/bin"
ExecStart=/usr/share/nginx/html/pair/venv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind 127.0.0.1:8001 ft_pair.wsgi:application


[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target


i faced this problem but when i run the project on AWS Amazone linux with this command python manage.py runserver
my project working fine also with this command working fine on server.
/usr/share/nginx/html/pair/venv/bin/gunicorn --bind 127.0.0.1:8001 ft_pair.wsgi:application
I want this with gunicorn service.
enter image description here
This image is working fine when i run project with command.
I'm very thankfull.
